Does posting a picture of a book on social media for only personal use infringe intellectual property law?
Does posting a cover of a book or page of a book on social media (e.g. Facebook, Instagram, WhatsApp) infringe copyright or intellectual property law if the inside cover mentioned about copyrights (I'm just only doing for personal use)? What if the inside cover of the book never mentioned about any copyrights? Thanks.

What does "inside cover mentioned about copyrights" mean? Do you mean there's a copyright notice inside the book? In Berne Convention countries (including the US), copyright is automatic, the notice is not required.

@Barmar Yes, if there is no copyright notice inside the book, does that mean I can take a photo of any of the pages and post it on social media for personal use?

See https://www.bitlaw.com/copyright/formalities.html for what a notice does. Lack of a notice does not allow you to make copies.

@Barmar Then how do I post an image of a page in a book or its cover on social media without infringing copyright?

Contact the publisher and get permission.


Does posting a cover of a book or page of a book on social media (e.g.
Facebook, Instagram, WhatsApp) infringe copyright or intellectual
property law if the inside cover mentioned about copyrights (I'm just
only doing for personal use)? What if the inside cover of the book
never mentioned about any copyrights?

Posting a cover of a book whose copyright has not expired (even if there is no copyright notice) is prima facie copyright infringement.
Whether a fair use defense to this prime facie showing of copyright infringement could be established would be highly fact specific. Personal use only would not establish a fair use defense. But, if the covers were used as part of a piece of literary criticism (particularly one that discussed the covers), it would likely be fair use.

Also: No company would go after someone showing just the outside of their book, for it would be horrible publicity.

Would a book reviewer require permission to include a photo of the cover with their review then?

@ohwilleke so I can't even post an image of the inside of the book for personal use if there is any copyright notice?

@HelloDarkWorld The copyright notice doesn't matter.

@ohwilleke Then how do I post an image of a page in a book or its cover on social media without infringing copyright?

@HelloDarkWorld Depending on what your use is, it may help to photograph it in such a way that most of the text is not readable in your photograph. I shouldn't be able to "read your photograph" as a substitute for reading the actual book. That's one of the fair use factors, but there are others. If the portion you are reproducing in the photograph is for criticism or commentary, that may be allowed, too. But usually no one can say for certain on things like this. The only sure way is to get permission first, or just not to post it.
